# Achieving a GIF effect by using code - how is it done?

Tags: jquery, gif, css-sprites

Whilst reasearching for a project, I came across Lacoste's web page http://www.lacoste.com/live/usa/home

What intrigued me the most about the design of this page was the display of the looks, which when hovered turn into what seems to be 360 animated GIF, but on closer inspection I realised they are actually really wide JPEGS with views from all the angles which somehow move left and right to create the impression of animated movement.

How is this achieved? I imagine it's some sort of JavaScript that does it, but I would appreciate it if someone could explain with a little example of code what the basics of this are.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maked it with fixed size div, background-image and change of background position.
**Check it here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/LLAlive/NX2FG/

Comment: That works great, thank you! The only problem I'm having is – I tried using this with a slightly bigger image and it's not working. Do you know if there is a max size at which this would work? Regards!

Answer (score 2):

the keywords you need to be searching for are `css sprites`, and there is a good explanation here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: aren't CSS sprites called that because they are commanded by CSS (ergo, by the top/bottom/left/right property that changes on hover) ?

Comment: the example above had more to do with creating a 'carousel' effect javascript, as explaineed by @LLAlive